# Starting TexStudio from batch file doesn't compile

Tags: miktex, compiling, texstudio, makeindex

I'm using MikTex portable and TexStudio on a USB drive. On the top most folder level I placed a batch file starting the texstudio.exe. When I try to compile any document, it doesen't run the command makeindex. Then I tried to start TexStudio via it's orginal texstudio.exe and it worked perfectly.

So I think the problem lies somewhere in my batch file, maybe something regarding the user permissions?

I would be glad if someone can help me on that :)

[image: Commands][image]

Comment: post the content of your batch file.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your textudio preferences? This sounds like it might be a problem with your path, which is different for things launched from a batch file than with clicking on icons.

Comment: Did you specify the full path to `makeindex` or do you rely that the program is found within your $PATH variable?

Comment: mmm, the relative paths look fine, as far as I can tell. So maybe not a problem with paths.

Comment: Do you get any error message when you try to run makeindex?

Comment: It says: Can not start: "../MiKTeX/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -synctex = 1 -interaction = nonstopmode "Report" .tex

Unable to start: "../MiKTeX/texmfs/install/miktex/bin/makeindex.exe" "Report" .idx

Comment: do you really have spaces in the synctex call should be -synctex=1 which it appears in your images. I see you have a mix of calls to 2016 ! TeX Live and MiKTeX this is to be avoided at all costs The commands should NOT have anything in front, the first one should start **latex.exe** and the system should find it having paths will add to interference. Only one TeX engine should be active if possible via the path variable at command prompt before running your batch file. What is the response from entering> path

Comment: Your setup has a mix of implied absolute and implied relative paths which are causing the underlying problem. you need to consider how actions are called different ways. this is why you should not have defined relative paths inside TeXstudio they may work sometimes but not others. The key is to have NO paths defined in TeXstudio and rely on the priorities within the system path see the example second line where MiKTeX folder is defined at start of path then ANYTIME a call to **pdflatex.exe** is made the MiKTeX one will be actioned before any other older TeX Live one on the target machine.

Comment: Besides the mess of the settings, when I start the exe file it works fine. When I access the exe file via my batch file it doesn't work. It doesn't "feel" like the problem lies within the TexStudio settings. But I cleaned them up anyway :D

Comment: not from your usb but on your desktop run cmd enter> pdflatex.exe does it report texlive, MiKTeX or not found  if you see ** use ctrl c to exit now enter> where /r c: pdfLaTeX (yes that is c:) and again pointing at your usb drive>where /r h: pdfLaTeX --how does your machine know which one to use ? is there only one in total ? when texstudio runs> txs:path which folder will it find pdfLaTeX in first if you want it to find one on h: then you have to say h:\... it does not easily understand ..\ when you start a batch file in h:\ there is no physical ..\ you need to use syntax like %~d0

Answer (score 1):

Generally (corporate installations excepted) one of the reasons for a portable TeX installation is the ease with which one current copy can be used on different platforms and with different editors (i.e. my requirements)
Keeping the different parts in separate folders is ideal and a top level batch file makes sense. So the typical contents of such a batch file may be

DO NOT use this one it is **just an example of steps** to consider

First are there additional dependencies such as Perl for latexmk or pdf viewer or converters like GS note in this first case there are NO quotes because there are no spaces

```
set path=%~d0\Imagemagic\imagemagick;%~d0\GS\ghostscript;%path%
```

Obviously MiKTeX (or TeX Live etc.) need to be on path and in this case quotes are needed because there is a space

```
set PATH="%~d0\MiKTeX app\texmfs\install\miktex\bin;%path%"
```

You will need something to let you update MiKTeX on the fly etc and the simplest is to let it run in the background (remember this is not a working example use your own paths)

```
start "" "%~d0%~p0texmfs\install\miktex\bin\miktex-console.exe" --hide --mkmaps
```

Lastly we need our editor (perhaps with optional variable for drag and drop a tex file)

```
"%~d0\tex studio\texstudio2.12.14\texstudio.exe" "%1"
```

It is useful to keep the dos console open to allow command line usage or checking

So a final line could be

```
%comspec% /k
```